# Forçar CSS no IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Tenho um widget na minha página e ele está lendo um CSS externo, gostaria que carregasse o meu CSS como principal no Internet Explorer 11. Todos os outros navegadores carregam normalmente, mas preciso que funcione o IE.

Usei o "!important" no css e mesmo assim não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Minha solução funcionou?

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo, não está "forçando" o meu css.

Comment: Eu também testei sem sucesso. Vou pesquisar alguma outra maneira.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infelizmente, parece que as implementações antigas do CSS no Internet Explorer não permite usar o `!important` de forma convencional.

Se você simplesmente sobrepor ou atualizar um atributo **não vai dar certo**. Isso somente dará certo caso esteja usando Media Queries, como para fazer um site responsivo.

Na realidade o *"correto"* seria você não precisar sobrepor usando o `!important`, mas sim, usar uma hierarquia de classes.

Por exemplo:

```
.class1 {
color: #555 !important;
}

.class1 {
color: #FFF;
}

.class1 {
color: #000;
}
```

A cor que o Internet Explorer interpretará será a #000, pois é a que vem depois e por isso a mesma sobrepõe as anteriores.

Comment: Mas os outros browsers não interpretarão também, somente a cor #000?

Comment: Não, os outros interpretarão a #555 pelo uso do !important.

Comment: Entendí, então o important só não funciona no IE?

Comment: Em versões antigas eu diria. Eu ignoraria essas versões na hora de desenvolver.

Comment: Ótima resposta ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ter duas folhas de estilos e utilizar uma para IE e outras para os demais navegadores.

```
<!--[if IE]> <link href="somente_ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> <link href="geral.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Isso já foi tentando e não funciona, amigo :/

Comment: O que não funciona @TiagoP.C?